# Unicenta password encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, hash, passwords

i'm trying to develop i new version of Unicenta opos _ it's an Openbravo open source project _ working on android platforme, i'm almost done with, but i'm still have some problems with password part.

my problem is:
the Unicenta opos save the password in a mysql database using Sha1 encryption, so when i tried to do the same in my android application it does not gave me the same Encryption for the same password, then what i did; i looked for the Unicenta code source and i picked up the Encryption code and i put it as it is in my App;

Encryption function from unicenta code source:

```
public static String hashString(String sPassword) {

      if (sPassword == null || sPassword.equals("")) {
          return "empty:";
      } else {
          try {
              MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
              md.update(sPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
              byte[] res = md.digest();
              return "sha1:" + StringUtils.byte2hex(res);
          } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
              return "plain:" + sPassword;
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              return "plain:" + sPassword;
          }
      }
    }
```

so it's so clear that this function take a String as parametre (the Password) and return the (password encrypted)

but the problem is when i try to encrypt a password for example (**0000**) with unicenta opos it gaves me: (**sha1:B6589FC6AB0DC82CF12099D1C2D40AB994E8410C)** and with my android app using the same methode used by unicenta it gaves me another Hash (**sha1:39dfa55283318d31afe5a3ff4a0e3253e2045e43**)

sorry for being long, i hope if someone intersted!

thank u

Comment: Do not use simple hashing algorithms for password storage **ESPECIALLY** if you don't salt them. Check if the Unicenta opos' hash output is consistent (same hash across multiple runs) as it might be salting the data prior to hashing. The "correct" pure SHA-1 digest of '0000' is indeed '39dfa55283318d31afe5a3ff4a0e3253e2045e43'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicenta does not directly encrypt/hash passwords. Look at byte2hex and JEditorText.java for how it manipulates the input password before encryption. So 9802 is changed into '***Wt a***' without quote and then hashed.

**First function to hash:**

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");                   
                    md.update(sPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    byte[] res = md.digest();                    
                    return "sha1:" + StringUtils.byte2hex(res);
```

***byte2hex***:

**StringUtils.java**

```
public static String byte2hex(byte[] binput) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(binput.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < binput.length; i++) {
            int high = ((binput[i] & 0xF0) >> 4);
            int low = (binput[i] & 0x0F);
            sb.append(hexchars[high]);
            sb.append(hexchars[low]);
        }
//sb : 56E048B73E9B3EFF42C509B772AF6941FF0B5BA5
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

**Finally look into JEditorText.java:**

```
    private static final char[] CHAR_abc1_1 = {'.', '?', '!', ',', '1', ';', ':'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_abc1_2 = {'a', 'b', 'c', '2', '\u00a0'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_abc1_3 = {'d', 'e', 'f', '3', '\u201a'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_abc1_4 = {'g', 'h', 'i', '4', '\u00a1'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_abc1_5 = {'j', 'k', 'l', '5'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_abc1_6 = {'m', 'n', 'o', '6', '\u00a4', '\u00a2'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_abc1_7 = {'p', 'q', 'r', 's', '7'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_abc1_8 = {'t', 'u', 'v', '8', '\u00a3', '\ufffd'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_abc1_9 = {'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '9'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_abc1_0 = {' ', '0'};

    private static final char[] CHAR_ABC1_1 = {'.', '?', '!', ',', '1', ';', ':'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_ABC1_2 = {'A', 'B', 'C', '2', '\u00b5'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_ABC1_3 = {'D', 'E', 'F', '3', '\u00c9'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_ABC1_4 = {'G', 'H', 'I', '4', '\u00cd'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_ABC1_5 = {'J', 'K', 'L', '5'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_ABC1_6 = {'M', 'N', 'O', '6', '\u00d1', '\u00d3'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_ABC1_7 = {'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', '7'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_ABC1_8 = {'T', 'U', 'V', '8', '\u00da', '\u00dc'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_ABC1_9 = {'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '9'};
    private static final char[] CHAR_ABC1_0 = {' ', '0'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you

```
private String hashString(String s) {
        try {
            // Create SHA-1 Hash
            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            digest.update(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

            // Create Hex String
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++)
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
            return hexString.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Just saying... comment on line 3 says 'Create MD5 Hash' when you're actually creating a SHA-1 hash. And also use getBytes("UTF-8") instead of platform-specific getBytes() with no parameters.

Comment: Don't worry I was using this method to create MD5 and this will create SHA-1.

Comment: thanks @BirajZalavadia, actually your methode is the same as the one i found in the the unicenta code source, i gave it a try but it still dosn't give me "B6589FC6AB0DC82CF12099D1C2D40AB994E8410C" for the password "0000" :/

Comment: I just change it is it ok now? Working or not?

Comment: reallyyy u do get "B6589FC6AB0DC82CF12099D1C2D40AB994E8410C" for "0000"!! :o

Comment: it is four (0)zero or "o".

Comment: I am getting "39dfa55283318d31afe5a3ff4a0e3253e2045e43" for "0000"

Comment: yeah i get that, but actually the user i have in unicenta opos who has this encryption "B6589FC6AB0DC82CF12099D1C2D40AB994E8410C" has as password "0000" not just one zero "0"